# Can't seem to be able to figure how to submit a Mechanize form

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

This is my first try ever to make code for this, this is the issue so far. I'm trying to submit a registration form for a website, the easiest that I could find.

The website: https://www.cint.com/registration/Template07.aspx?Guid=4fb4a86f-734f-41dd-8399-820edf3b0d61&Recruitment=Standard_Dec2016

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8

import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.open('https://www.cint.com/registration/Template07.aspx?Guid=4fb4a86f-734f-41dd-8399-820edf3b0d61&Recruitment=Standa$
br.select_form(nr=0)
form = br.form
br.form['EmailAddress'] = 'ma@il.com'
br.form ['Gender'] = ['1']
br.form['YearOfBirth'] = ['1990']
br.form ['PostCode'] = '*MYPOSTALNUMBER*'
br.form ['Q_160809'] = ['2246480']
sub = br.submit()
print sub.geturl()
```

The error:

```
root@Python:~# python python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 12, in <module>
    br.form['EmailAddress'] = 'ma@il.com'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form_controls.py", line 1945, in __setitem__
    control = self.find_control(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form_controls.py", line 2331, in find_control
    return self._find_control(name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form_controls.py", line 2424, in _find_control
    raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching " + description)
mechanize._form_controls.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'EmailAddress'
```

Python version: Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the problem is the form has no field named 'EmailAddress', and throws a `ControlNotFoundError`.

To see which fields you need to fill out in your form, print them:

```
for field_name in br.form.controls:
    print field_name
```

The printed `field_name`s are what you need to populate with `br.form['field_name']`